# Using "Light theme" map on a dark themed phone

Tags: swift, xcode

I use MKMapView (Swift) on an Xcode project in order to show the user's location. However, after the recent iOS update that provides the user the option to go light or dark, the colors clash with the other, graphical elements (screendump).

The best thing in my situation is to force the map to be shown as light themed, regardless of the user's settings. Can this be done? And if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the map view's interface style:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3238086-overrideuserinterfacestyle